# Outdated graphic layout editor in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've got a strange problem. I am using Eclipse Indigo with ADT plugin for Android development.

My problem is that the Graphical Layout Editor is somehow outdated. It doesn't look like the version presented on android developers website. In my opinion, this version is maybe 3 years old, because in Google I/O 2011 there was presented a new version of this WYSIWYG editor. I think, I've got everything updated including Eclipse and Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following things:

- Eclipse Indigo is Version 3.7. We're currently at 4.3 SR1 (Keppler). You might want to replace your Eclipse with the current one. Note: You must download Eclipse from scratch. An Update `Check for Updates...` will update only within the current release (Indigo)
- Within the graphical editor of Eclipse, check if you're using an up to date SDK Version and Theme:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse Graphical Editor]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got the newest Android SDK Tools version 22.2.1.
I have also downloaded the newest Keppler IDE. For better imagination, here's the screenshot: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1024/obpq.jpg
If you compare this with the picture of Graphical Layout Editor on the official website: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#graphical-editor
There is a big difference.

Comment: My screen looks like yours and I have everything in the newest versions, too. I alos use the newest features succesfully, so that ok. The screenshot from Android looks a lot like Marketing: 60% of what really exists and 40% of what you want but never get :-)